# flowplayer works for all browser, but not in safari... why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, flowplayer

flowplayer doensn't work with safari, that is the code... what's the problem?! :S

thanx for help!

```
<div class="pictureLayer">
                    <a id="player" style="display:block;width:636px;height:407px" href="upload/4/video/video.flv"><object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flowplayer-3.1.5.swf" id="player_api"><param value="true" name="allowfullscreen"><param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess"><param value="high" name="quality"><param value="false" name="cachebusting"><param value="#000000" name="bgcolor"><param value="config={&quot;clip&quot;:{&quot;autoPlay&quot;:true,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;upload/4/video/video.flv&quot;},&quot;playerId&quot;:&quot;player&quot;,&quot;playlist&quot;:[{&quot;autoPlay&quot;:true,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;upload/4/video/video.flv&quot;}]}" name="flashvars"></object></a> 

    <!-- this will install flowplayer inside previous A- tag. -->
                    <script>
                        flowplayer("player", "flowplayer-3.1.5.swf", {
                                clip : {
                                    autoPlay: true
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    </script>
                </div>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: no nothing... this is strange :S

Comment: Flash up and running? :D